# How to bind list items to origin data context instead of list data context

Tags: wpf, data-binding

So I have this list of products, and the list is binded to the `Products` property successfully, and all of the data for items (`Name`, `Description`, `StartingPrice`) is binded successfully.

```
 <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Products}"
        HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
        ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="110"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="60"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        
                    <Grid Grid.Column="0">
                        <Rectangle Width="100" Height="100" Fill="Black" Margin="0,0,0,0" />
                    </Grid>
                        
                    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1">
                        <Label Content="{Binding Name}" Padding="0"/>
                        <Label Content="{Binding StartingPrice}" Padding="0"/>
                        <Label Content="Last Bidder" Padding="0"/>
                        <Label Content="Time left" Padding="0"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                        
                    <Label Grid.Column="2" Content="{Binding Description}" Padding="0" />
                        
                    <Grid Grid.Column="3">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Button Grid.Row="0" Content="Delete" Background="Red" Visibility="{Binding Path=DataContext.DeleteButtonVisibility}" />
                        <Button Grid.Row="1" Content="Bid" Background="LightGreen" Visibility="{Binding Path=DataContext.BidButtonVisibility}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

Now I want to show/hide `Bid` and `Delete` buttons.

This information is stored in `DeleteButtonVisibility` and `BidButtonVisibility` in the viewmodel where `Products` is also stored, and they change as planned from what debugged.

How I can bind these properties from items in list that has it's own `DataContext`?

Comment: This sounds not very clear, I assume your code is working right now? Of course actually, all the buttons of the list are Hidden/Visible because they are bound to the parent DataContext. Would you manage the visibility for each row individually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To bind the `Visibility` properties of the Buttons with the properties of view model where `Products` exists, you need to insert `RelativeSource` to their bindings and make them to look up to the parent `ListBox`.

```xml
Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}},
                     Path=DataContext.DeleteButtonVisibility, Mode=OneWay}
```